# OpenCV vector creation in C++ and storing to text file

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, vector, opticalflow

I have a very basic query about storing vectors in OpenCV, but since I've always worked in MATLAB, I am finding it really difficult to perform the same vector operations in C++.

So here's my problem, I have computed optical flow using the basic cvGoodFeaturesToTrack() and  cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK() functions and find the flow lines' end points and show them on the image as lines of optical flow.

However, I want to store these flow line end points in a vector and then save it as a text file which I can then send to MATLAB for reading.

I really don't know how I can create these vectors that store these points and save them on a text file.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Yash

Comment: what form are the flow line points currently in? array? another stl type?

Comment: Hi Ben,
The points are initially stored in variables 'corners1' and 'corners2' which are initialized as follows:

       `CvPoint2D32f* corners2 = new CvPoint2D32f[MAX_CORNERS];`

But then, for plotting here's what I do with these points:

               `CvPoint p0=cvPoint(cvRound(corners1[i].x),
         cvRound(corners1[i].y));`

Comment: In my previous comment the variable 'i' goes from 1 to the total number of corner points found. Thus basically, all the corner points are stored in 'corners1' and 'corners2' per frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the OP's comments on the question i think this is a good way to do it:

```
std::ofstream matlabFile;
matlabFile.open("pointsOutput.m");
matlabFile << "Corners = [ ...\n";
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CORNERS; ++i) {
    matlabFile << corners2[i].x << " " << corners2[i].y << "; ...\n";
}
matlabFile << "];";
matlabFile.close();
```

This code should give you the following file at the local directory:

pointsOutput.m:

```
Corners = [ ...
1 2; ...
3 4; ...
];
```

which in matlab will give you the fiollowing matrix:

```
Corners = 
    1 2
    3 4
```

Assuming you have two points in that list with x and y = 1 and 2, 3 and 4.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ben. I will try and implement it immediately.

Comment: For some strange reason, my compiler(Xcode) doesn't seem to detect fstream.h. It says 'fstream.h' not found, which is weird because I've defined the project as a CPP project and the code is also a .cpp.

Comment: Not sure if i can help with that. Maybe ask another SO question, Do you want to upvote the answer if it was good?

Comment: It works...turns out iostream.h is old-fashioned...simply typing in "iostream" worked.